# I am trying to run a nested for loop in r which subtracts each row of a variable in a data frame

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
Number Time 
1       10:25:00
2       10:35:15
3       10:42:26
```

For each number in the data frame I want to subtract Time, for example:

```
Number 1 = 10:25:00 - 10:35:15
Number 2 = 10:35:15 - 10:42:26
```

My code:

```
for (i in df$Number) {
    for (j in df$Time) {
        subtime <- df$Time[j] - df$Time[j+1]
      }
}
```

This code only results in NA

Answer (score 0):

Because `subtime` is reassigned in every loop, only the last value is returned when the loops finish. Further, at the last iteration, `j == length(df$Time)` so `j + 1` is out of bounds, so `df$Time[j + 1]` will be NA, which means the entire result is NA.

Instead in general you can do:

```
df$subtime <- c(NA, diff(df$Time))
```

where NA is the first instance replaced by a suitable default for the first instance. Your case may require additional treatment depending on the exact class of `df$Time`.

<sub>(You should consider creating an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data if you need further help. What you provided is pretty close, but not quite enough for us to be of help.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like this. The result is given in hours.

For example: 10:25:00 - 10:35:15 = - 00:10:15 = - (10/60) - (15/3600) = -0.1708333

```
a = data.frame(Number = c(1, 2, 3), Time = c("10:25:00", "10:35:15", "10:42:26"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x = 2

timeDiff = function(x, a){

  as.difftime(a[x, 2]) - as.difftime(a[x+1, 2]) 

}    

result = sapply(2:nrow(a), timeDiff, a)

result
```

Please note that it's impossible to compute such difference for case `Number 3`, ever since a fourth row would be necessary, and the data frame you provided has only 3 rows.

As per Stack Overflow's prompt, I can see you r a new user, Thus, for future nested for-loops, I recommend you explore sapply or lapply, as it will make your code look cleaner and easier to maintain.

If you need any further clarification, don't hesitate to comment my answer. :-)